# I need a 4TB+ single-sided NVME drive for my ultraportable laptop

Tags: ssd

I just purchased a Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9, and a [Sabrent 4TB Rocket 4 PLUS (SB-RKT4P-4TB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VF99PV8). Though both of these are NVME Gen 4, to my chagrin, the NVME drive purchased does not fit into the Thinkpad. It's too thick. Notice how one drive is so much further elevated off the surface.

[image: Two sided NVME and one sided nvme]

[image: One sided NVME on top of two sided NVME]

Are there any NVME drives above 2TB that are one-sided? Is there any mechanism in which I can shop this without purchasing them all and opening them up?

Comment: Try to check first the dimension of the SSD and compare with yours. Height can be 2.22mm to 3.5mm , so second should surely not replace the first. Aldo when getting higher capacity the height will generally  increase.

Comment: Clearly, if i bought every NVME hard drive I could easily compare the heights or examine the chips. I'm on this StackExchange so someone else can potentially save me the work.

Comment: Usually you can have the height in the description of items in web site : LxWxH.

Comment: From what I saw on Crucial you should use only single sided SSD. It seems the too thick one you show is double sided which may explain why it does not fit. The problem is that it will limit your possibilities for upgrading to high capacity.